# Access diagonal elements in a 2D array stored in a 1D array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

Suppose my 2D array is:

```
int a[4][4] = {
               1,0,0,0,
               0,1,0,0,
               0,0,1,0,
               0,0,0,1
              };
```

Suppose its stored in a 1D array as:

```
int b[16]={1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1};
```

In general, assume `a` is of size `m x n` and `b` is of size `mn`.
Using a single `for loop` I want to be able to access all the diagonal elements, i.e output should be 1 1 1 1.

I understand `A[i][j] = B[i*n+j];` but if I'm only using a single for loop, I don't have a `j index`.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit:

Note let m=n be for all practical purposes. The interface I'm using expects two separate variables for row and column size. But I'm only working with square matrices.

Comment: In the diagonal `i=j`. BTW, what is diagonal when `m != n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know your 2D array is a perfect square (i.e. exactly as many rows as columns), you don't need a `j` index:

As a 2D array:

```
for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", array[i][i];
}
```

As a 1D array:

```
for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", array[i*height+i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple to it for a 2-d array.

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
   printf("%d", a[i][i]);
```

And for a single dimension array, it is not difficult either.

```
for(int i=0; i<16; i=i+5)
   printf("%d", b[i]);
```

Comment: The array in question is 1D

Comment: Edited my answer to include 1D array too.

Comment: And it's still a 2D array

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, it's not.

Comment: You are still using two indexes to access it, what gives?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, oops, it is fixed now.

Comment: No problem, as @Stargateur said, take your time when editing :)

Answer (score 1):

You only needto consider the number of columns.

```
#define COLUMNS 4
#define ROWS 4

b[16]={1,0,0,0,
       0,1,0,0,
       0,0,1,0,
       0,0,0,1};

int i = 0;
for(; i < ROWS; i++ ){
  printf("%d\t",b[COLUMNS*i+i]);
}
```